# WPF MVVM 2 Usercontrols views with the same data context and ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have 2 usercontrol views, these are: `Bmw.xaml` and `Audi.xaml`.

In both xamls I add this:

```
<UserControl x:Class=TestProject.Views.Fragments.Audi
             <!--The standard code generated by visual studio-->
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:TestProject.ViewModels"
        <Grid>
            <!--XAML CODE-->
        </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In both bmw.caml.cs and audi.xaml.cs I have this in my constructor:

```cs
public Audi()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new BrandViewModel();
}
```

And

```cs
public BMW()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new BrandViewModel();
}
```

In the ViewModel are my functions, to keep it simple when the ViewModel is called by the Audi I want to call the function ActionAudi() and when it is called by the BMW I want to call ActionBMW().

Is there a good way to know in the viewModel class whether it belongs to the audi or bmw usercontrol? Because depending on this there has to be executed different logic.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to use the same ViewModel twice, when you want separate logic for BMW and Audi?

Comment: Because I also want to use mostly the same logic for both Views, but also some separate logic.

Comment: Use an interface where the two share common logic and props... or create a base class. You can also add a param to your constructor to take what vehicle make and determine what you need to do.

Comment: How are you switching these usercontrols out?

Comment: I want to display both usercontrols in the same window. For example BrandModel AudiModel = new BrandModel() and BrandModel BmwModel = new BrandModel(). And I want to display AudiModel.On in the Audi usercontrol and the BmwModel.On in the Bmw usercontrol. Because they use the same Model but the values don't have to be the same. (The data in the model comes from a PLC. So the data for the BMW has to be loaded in the BmwModel instance.) But maybe it's better to use two different ViewModels?

Comment: If they have different property values then isn't that going to be a bit of a problem with one instance?  Mostly the same logic sounds like  it could be a base class but you could also inject funcs or actions via a factory to build your functionality if it's varied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create an enum to define which brand do you have. Like this

```
public enum Brands
{
    Audi,
    BMW,
    Vinfast
}
```

Second, modify your ViewModel's constructor to some think like this.

```
public BrandViewModel(Brands brand)
{
    // passing brand to a field or property
}
```

Finally, set your DataContext by new constructor you just created.

```
public Audi()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new BrandViewModel(Brands.Audi);
}
```

and

```
public BMW()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new BrandViewModel(Brands.BMW);
}
```